# Microsoft Outlook calendar event property isorganizer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I encountered a problem when creating an event in the calendar from an external user, I can change the organizer, but I can’t cancel the mailing for events, I’m trying to change the “isorganizer” property to false, but there is no result, I tried to specify using singleValueExtendedProperties, I came across “2.392 PidNameCalendarIsOrganizer" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/0f0dbb53-936c-47dc-985d-f0917e0a092c, but I can’t write the ID correctly, please help

```
PATCH
{
    "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "id": "boolean {'id'}",
            "value": "**false**"
        }
    ]
}
```

RESPONCE

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
        "message": "PropertyId values may only be in one of the following formats: 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Name propertyName', 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Id propertyId' or 'MapiPropertyType propertyTag'."
    }
}
```

I tried to enter the ID in different ways, but the format was not the same